# Why do I have difference in output to console

Tags: powershell

Why do I have difference in output?

```
$f = Get-WindowsFeature
$f[1].GetType()
$f[1]
```

output

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Name                      : ADCS-Cert-Authority
DisplayName               : Certification Authority
Description               : Certification Authority (CA) is used to issue and manage certificates. Multiple CAs can be linked to form a public key infrastructure.
...
```

and

```
$f = Get-WindowsFeature   
$f[1]
```

output

```
Display Name                                    Name                       Install State
------------                                    ----                       -------------
[ ] Certification Authority                     ADCS-Cert-Authority            Available
```

Also get more verbose output from `$lines.GetType()` if don't remove `$f[1]`.

```
$f = Get-WindowsFeature
$f[1]

$lines = Get-Content featuresinarray.txt | Where {$_ -notmatch '^\s+$'} 
$lines.GetType()
```

output

```
Display Name                                    Name                       Install State
------------                                    ----                       -------------
[ ] Certification Authority                     ADCS-Cert-Authority            Available

Module                     : CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary
Assembly                   : mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
TypeHandle                 : System.RuntimeTypeHandle
DeclaringMethod            : 
BaseType                   : System.Array
```

But now if I add `$f.GetType()` after `$f = Get-WindowsFeature` I get short output from both `$lines.GetType()` and `$f.GetType()`:

```
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

If I add `$f.GetType()` after `$lines.GetType()` then I have 2 times verbose output of Array class in ouput. So why this is happening?

Comment: whats the difference you got?

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta I updated the question

Comment: so it is giving properly only. See the base type along with the other information. Whats your confusion ? Could you please post the two outputs and tell what exactly is the confusion

Comment: I don't understand what is the reason that I get short or verbose output from $f[0] or from "some variable".GetType(). Output is just one row definition of class/object or each property definition like Format-List -Property * generates

Comment: [Related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/). [Also related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40344479/1630171).

Comment: @Lavandil: Check Ansgar Links. Its properly explained