# Transpose list to matrix in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to adapt some code I have found online and have the following:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq ‘security’} -SearchBase ‘OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local’
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase “dc=corp,dc=test,dc=local”

$addADGroupMembers = @{}

foreach($group in $groups) {
    $addADGroupMembers.Add($group.Name, $group.ObjectGUID)
}

$htUsers = @{}
$htProps = @{}
$addADGroupMembers.Keys | foreach {$htProps.$_=$null}
foreach ($group in $addADGroupMembers.GetEnumerator()){
    foreach ($user in $group.Value){
        if (!$htUsers.ContainsKey($user)){
            $htProps.UserID = $user
            $htUsers.$user = $htProps.Clone()
        }
        ($htUsers.$user).$($group.Name) = 1
    }
}
```

This gives me a list of users, each with a list elements as below:

```
Accounts Administrators                                   : False
Support Read-Write                                        : False
Username                                                  : user1@test.local
Purchasing Read-Write                                     : False
Developers Administrators                                 : False
SharePoint 365 Administrators                             : False
Operations Read-Write                                     : False

Accounts Administrators                                   : True
Support Read-Write                                        : False
Username                                                  : joe@test.local
Purchasing Read-Write                                     : False
Developers Administrators                                 : False
SharePoint 365 Administrators                             : True
Operations Read-Write                                     : False

#snip...
```

But I have two things that i cant work out:

1. How can I get the User Principal Name included? I am unable to look this up from ObjectGUID and cant work out how to lookup from my users array.
2. How to sort this into a printed matrix, where I have rows of users down the side (and the UPN is the first column), and their associated groups (with a True in if they are a member) along the top.

This would form the below:

```
                    Accounts        Support        Sales
User1@domain.com      1                             1
User2@domain.com                       1
```

Thanks for the help in advance, will issue some reputation points for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use plain hashtables for this. Put UPN and group names in a (ordered) hashtable and create a custom object from that:

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'security'" -SearchBase 'OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=local'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=corp,dc=test,dc=local" -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
  $props = [ordered]@{ 'Username' = $_.UserPrincipalName }
  $groups | ForEach-Object {
    $props[$_.Name] = $false
  }

  $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object -Expand Name | ForEach-Object {
    if ($props.ContainsKey($_)) {
      $props[$_] = $true
    }
  }

  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
}
```

The output would look somewhat like this:

```
Username            Accounts        Support        Sales
--------            --------        -------        -----
User1@domain.com        True          False         True
User2@domain.com       False           True        False
...
```

If you want empty values instead of `False` for groups the user isn't a member of replace `$false` with the empty string (`''`) and replace `$true` with whatever marker you want to use (`1`, `'x'`, ...).

Comment: What would the output look like for this?

Comment: Many thanks it is indeed returning a list of usernames, line by line will update my question to explain, the final step is to transpose the array to a matrix.

Comment: @g18c `... |  Format-Table`. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40344479/1630171).