# How to format the output better?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following output that keeps outputting from loop:

```
Write-Host "`r`n $server | $db | success! | [$Time] "
```

The current output I get is like this:

[image: output]

Is there a way i can make this equivalently formatted?

so that it would end up more like this:

[image: proper_output]

Comment: you should create an object and output this either with a format cmdlet or just as it is ... Powershell will format it for you.

Comment: @Olaf so something like this: $output = Write-host "`r`n $server | $db | success! | [$Time] "? if its just as it is, how would it be any different?

Comment: No. Something like `[PSCustomobject]@{'Server'=$server; 'DB'=$db; 'Result'='success'; 'Time'=$time}`.

Comment: May also be useful to check out the [Format-Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344479/1630171)

Comment: @romellem thats what i considered initially but since its not really a table...i am not sure how this would be integrated

Comment: Build. Custom. Objects.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers im reading through your post as we speak :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers so the object, i.e. 'Server', i dont want to output that..only the value. can i discard those like 'Server', 'DB', etc? also, i noticed in your post that the output is being done backwards to frontwards. like c,e,d,b,a...wouldnt that ruin my ordering to begin with in my case?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers so i just used it in the script as pscustom object, asn besides the fact its outputting the property name (i.e server, db,time) which i was hoping it would be possibly to ignore them, its still not formatting equivalently. its outputting the exact same zigzag pattern as the current output i have in my post

Comment: you can do it in two steps ... [1] get the length of the longest item in each column [2] use the `-f` string format operator with the alignment option to fit each into the needed space. this ... -f Format operator - PowerShell - SS64.com — https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: @Lee_Dailey how would i get the length though? i guess i can count what the current out put is...is that what you mean?

Comment: You may take a step back and take some time to start to learn the very basics of Powershell. That would save you from a lot of missunderstandings, wasted time and frustration. It will even help you to understand the help you get here or in other forums.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oh i see. something like this: Left and right align text:
PS C:\> "|{0,-10}| |{1,10}|" -f "hello", "world"
|hello     ||     world|

Comment: @Cataster - yes, that is the idea. you will need to tweak it carefully, but it allows a great deal of control.

Comment: @Cataster - you are quite welcome! glad to help a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Lee_Dailey, I was able to get the formatting!

I used the `-f` operator:

```
"`r`n {0,1} | {1,-32} | {2,-20} | {3,1} " -f "$server","$db","success!","[$Time]"
```

https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

Comment: ha ha .  I liked this approach although customobjects are better. :)

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta I wanted the custom object to work but unfortunately since the whole script itself is,looping, the headers continue to be outputted each iteration :(. The f operator however works lovely: D