# Get the count of a formatted table in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, count, active-directory

I am working on a script that gets locked users from the AD and then counts them and exports their names.
It looks like this:

```
$server = "multiverse"
$searchbase = "OU=Earth,DC=616,DC=ads"
$locked = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $searchbase -LockedOut -UsersOnly | Get-ADUser -Server $server -Properties * | ft SamAccountName, Name 
write-host $locked
$amount = ($locked).Count
write-host $amount
```

I can get the correct users. `$locked` looks like this:

```
SamAccountName  Name                      
--------------- ----                      
spiderman       Parker, Peter          
hulk            Banner, Bruce          
ironman         Stark, Tony  
thor            Odinson, Thor          
loki            Laufeyson, Loki          
captainamerica  Rogers, Steve
stanlee         Lee, Stan
```

But from what I understand, there are 7 locked users and therefore `$count` should be

```
7
```

but the output is

```
11
```

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Comment: Format-Table adds the headings and the line of hyphens to $locked. You should define $locked then use format-table only when you want to output to the screen e.g. $locked | format-table SamAccountName, Name and $locked.count

Comment: Do not use `Format-*` cmdlets when you need to further process the output. [Maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344479/1630171).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while trying to solve it myself, I noticed this:

```
$server = "multiverse"
$searchbase = "OU=Earth,DC=616,DC=ads"

$locked = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $searchbase -LockedOut -UsersOnly | Get-ADUser -Server $server -Properties * #took away the format-table from here
$lockedtable = $locked | ft SamAccountName, Name #made a new variable here to output it as a table
write-host $lockedtable

$amount = ($locked).Count #and this .count now refers to the pure $locked and the the formated one
write-host $amount
```

What I was doing wrong was trying to count a formated version of `$locked`. If I put the `.count` to the pure `$locked`, the counting is correct.

I'm happy I could solve it by myself :).

edit: Thanks to your comments I now also understand why it counted 11. Thanks for your efforts.